# bypass youtube account pop-up with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

i have tried to get past this pseudo pop up in the following ways:

`WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID , 'introAgreeButton'))).click()`

`WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH , '//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]'))).click()`

none of the ways described seem to work.
is there any way to bypass this annoying pop-up ?

Comment: I can't reproduce that pop up, but it's likely in an iframe. So look here for infor: https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/FpKPXG6)
this is the code of the page.
the pop-up appears at any driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/") if you don't have any accounts already logged in which I suppose is rather impossible when working directly with the driver.

Comment: No, I get a differnt style pop up. Your image doesn't reveal the entire DOM. Your source code shows an iframe in it. Did you look at my link?

Answer (score 1):

Ive came across on same problem. The solution is:

```
try:
    driver._switch_to.frame("iframe")
    aggreeButton = driver.find_element_by_id("introAgreeButton")
    aggreeButton.click()
except:
    print("failed")
```

to move out the current frame to the page level

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is updated for July 2022

```
if 'consent.youtube.com' in driver.current_url: # THIS IS THE CHECK
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="VfPpkd-LgbsSe VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-dgl2Hf nCP5yc AjY5Oe DuMIQc LQeN7 IIdkle"]').click()
```

This will skip the 'Before you continue to Youtube screen'

Answer (score -1):

I can't get that pop-up to occur on my attempts when I navigate to YouTube; but, I suspect that this is a dialog or alert. If you check the `Elements` tab using the `Chrome Dev Tools` ( F12 ), that should tell you. Then, use the `find_element` by `xpath` to click on "I agree"

**UPDATED - Modified XPATH to the iron-overlay-backdrop tag**

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iron-overlay-backdrop[@class='opened']//button[text()='I agree']").click()
```

After that, wait for the modal / dialog to disappear or be removed from the `DOM` and continue doing what you're doing

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to point me to do, 
I know how to get into the Dev Tools, and copy the element's XPATH.
This pop-up should appear on a fresh browser, with no google account logged in.

Comment: @Ionut-AlexandruBaltariu - I am not able to get this pop-up; but, if you can see the `DOM` using the `Chrome Dev Tools` , then you should be able to see if this pop-up is a modal or is a `div` with a role of `dialog` or something similar. Once you determine this, you should be able to use `xpath` to navigate to it. If, however, the modal / dialog / pop-up is inside of an `iframe`, then you should use the `driver.switch_to.frame()` method and then navigate to the button using `xpath`. This would be my approach. If you can, can you please give us a Screenshot of the `HTML` Code? This would help.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/FpKPXG6)
This is the HTML code.

Comment: @Ionut-AlexandruBaltariu - I see. Okay. Then, based on the image ( if you can, expand the `iron-overlay-backdrop` code ), I think that your button resides inside of the `iron-overlay-backdrop` which means that you should start off your `xapth` with:  `//iron-overlay-backdrop[@class='opened']` and then go and dive into the button. Since the code is not expanded, I cannot see where your button exists. If you can, please expand that `iron-overlay-backdrop` so I can see more of the code.